# How can I get the latest "flagged revision" using wiktionary/wikipedia api in python?

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, wiktionary

Some language versions of Wiktionary/Wikipedia include "flagged revision."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Flagged_revisions/Sighted_versions

How can I create a url to get the latest "flagged revision"?

This code always returns the latest version not necessarily "flagged":

https://URL/w/api.php?action=parse&page=PAGE_NAME&prop=text

Python example implementation:

```
URL = "https://de.wiktionary.org/w/api.php"
soup = requests.get(URL, {'page': 'Katze', 'action': 'parse', 'format': 'json'})
```

Comment: This question is the same as [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78187345). Is this your alternate account? If so, please edit the old question (using the first account) instead.